# Does the National Assembly for Wales have to vote on the "Great Repeal Bill"?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, government, brexit, wales

We're aware by now that the Scottish Parliament [will have to have its own vote on the "Great Repeal Bill"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/what-if-holyrood-rejects-its-version-of-the-great-repeal-bill)

Given that the reason behind Scotland having to vote on this independently seems to be based on the fact that the great repeal bill will trespass into areas where legislative competency is devolved to Scotland. Is the same not true for Wales where the National Assembly for Wales has [full legislative competency](https://academic.oup.com/slr/article-abstract/33/2/151/1659426/Wales-Devolution-and-Sovereignty?redirectedFrom=fulltext) on [certain areas of Law and Policy](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/devolution-settlement-wales).

Answer (score 1):

**Kinda, Sorta - Yes?**

It seems that Plaid Cymru / Party of Wales has tabled an amendment to a motion in the Assembly that would essentially convert EU Law to Welsh Law where this pertains to the devolved areas.

> Plaid Cymru has this evening won a major victory in the National Assembly by winning an amendment calling for an EU Continuation Bill for Wales.
>
> The Plaid Cymru Assembly Group tabled the amendment to what it believed to be an inadequate motion by the Labour Welsh Government which simply noted the triggering of Article 50 and publication of the UK Government's Repeal Bill White Paper.
>
> The amendment sought to bring forward a Continuation Bill in order to uphold Wales's constitution and convert into Welsh law all European regulations related to devolved policy areas.
>
> Last week the UK Government White Paper outlined proposals that posed a threat to powers over matters already devolved to Wales.

The quote is from Plaid's own reporting on this - when/if the "Continuation Bill" becomes a thing I'll update this.

[Plaid secures major victory on EU Continuation Bill for Wales](http://www2.partyof.wales/plaid_secures_major)